# How to downsample some of the samples in RNA-seq data?

Tags: r, rna-seq, differential-expression, gene-expression

I have 40 samples and these are into two groups. I would like to perform a differential analysis between two groups. The library size of the samples is very low. But there are two samples (GroupA_12 and GroupB_2) in which the number of counts is too large compared to other samples. Please check the library sizes below:

[image]

I wanted to downsample these two cases and then would like to perform differential analysis. May I know how to downsample those two samples.

Any help is appreciated. thanq.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few options:

1. Downsample the fastq files and rerun the entire analysis. You can do this with `seqtk sample`.
2. Downsample the BAM files, which you can do with `samtools view -s`.
3. Divide all of the counts in the counts files by some factor and round that to an integer.

I personally prefer option 2, since it's quick and doesn't usually have any side-effects unless you use two-pass alignment or did the quantification with something like salmon. Option 3 is always tempting, but I have to say I've never been convinced that this consistently produces similar enough results to options 1 or 2.

Comment: thanks for the reply @Devon Ryan, Yes, I feel that the 3rd option is much easier. To use the 2nd option, I have to mention that the raw read counts of the transcripts were extracted from the `stringtie` step using `prepDE.py` python script [https://ccb.jhu.edu/software/stringtie/index.shtml?t=manual] Will there be any problem?

Comment: I don't use stringTie, so I can't comment with certainty.

Comment: ok. And if I have to use the 2nd option, Is this right? `samtools view -s number GroupA_12.bam >  GroupA_12_new.bam` What I should give the fixed number for downsampling?

Comment: If you need 20% then 1234.2. 1234 is just a seed for reproducibility, `.2` is the fraction to keep.

Comment: Small question. How to decide the fraction of reads to keep? I mean 0.2 or 0.5 or something else? On what basis I should give the fraction?

Comment: You’re trying to make the library sizes similar.

Comment: yes...so any cutoff is fine?

Comment: Just eye ball a fraction from that graph.